# Verifying $\mathrm \rho \frac{D\psi}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\rho \psi) + \nabla \cdot (\rho \psi \mathbf v \mathrm)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am currently attempting to show that for any scalar or vector field variable $(\psi)$ that $\mathrm \rho \frac{D\psi}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\rho \psi) + \nabla \cdot (\rho \psi \mathbf v \mathrm)$, for which $\rho$ = Density, $\psi$ = Any scalar/vector field variable, and $\mathbf v$ = Wind vector.

From $\frac{D}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \mathbf v \cdot \mathrm \nabla$,
I have gotten $\frac{D \psi}{Dt}=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} +  \mathbf v \cdot \mathrm \nabla \psi$

Multiplying by $\rho$, I have gotten $\rho \frac{D \psi}{Dt}=\rho \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + \rho \mathbf v \cdot \mathrm \nabla \psi$.

Through the Continuity Equation ($\frac {\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \rho \mathbf v = 0$), I get $\rho \frac{D \psi}{Dt}=\rho \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + \psi \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \psi \nabla \cdot \rho \mathbf v+ \rho \mathbf v \cdot \mathrm \nabla \psi$.

It is at this point that I am stuck and am uncertain of how to proceed with this problem. Can I change $\psi \nabla \cdot \rho \mathbf v+ \rho \mathbf v \cdot \mathrm \nabla \psi$ into $\nabla \cdot \rho \psi \mathbf v$ directly through vector identities with the del operator and $\mathbf v$? If so, what then must I do with the other half of the equation? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey! Would you mind clarifying what $\rho$, $\psi$ and $\mathbf v$ are?

Comment: Note $\nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{v})=\rho (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}) + (\nabla \rho) \cdot \mathbf{v}$ (generally true for a scalar field $\rho$ and vector field $\mathbf{v}$, they don't have to be related by a continuity equation). I think this might be the identity you needed?

Comment: @jlammy
$\rho$ = Density;
$\psi$ = Any scalar or vector;
$\mathbf v$ = Wind vector

Comment: @Ian Would that also hold true for $\psi \nabla \cdot \rho \mathbf v + \rho \mathbf v \cdot \nabla \psi = \nabla \cdot \rho \psi \mathbf v$?

Comment: Uhh...I would write $\nabla \cdot (\rho \psi \mathbf{v}) = \nabla(\rho \psi) \cdot \mathbf{v} + \rho \psi (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})$. That might turn out like you said after you simplify further?

Comment: Your last line is almost there. Because of product rules,
$$\rho\partial_t\psi+\psi\partial_t\rho=\partial_t(\rho\psi)$$
And
$$\psi\nabla\cdot(\rho\boldsymbol u)+\rho\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\psi=\nabla\cdot(\rho\psi\boldsymbol u)$$